# I don't know why I return IEnumerable instead of List (C#)

Tags: c#, list, generics, ienumerable

```
List<string> MealNames = FoodPlanerList.Select( p => p.Meals.ToList().Select(t => t.name).ToList<String>());
```

> Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to`System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266) (FoodPlanViewer)

I try to return a String List. I have the `List<Meals>`. Meals contains the string name. I'm not able to return a `List<string>` with all the names of the `List<Meals>`.

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo, your ) are at the wrong positions:

```
List<string> MealNames =  FoodPlanerList.Select( p => p.Meals).Select(t => t.name).ToList<String>();
```

If Meals is a list, SelectMany would be the right function

```
List<string> MealNames =  FoodPlanerList.SelectMany( p => p.Meals).Select(t => t.name).ToList<String>();
```

perhaps you also want to insert a distinct operation

```
List<string> MealNames =  FoodPlanerList.SelectMany( p => p.Meals).Select(t => t.name).Distinct().ToList<String>();
```

Comment: No, Linq returns `IEnumerable<List<string>>` not `List<string>`

Comment: With your syntax C# can't resolve t.name

Comment: that completely depends how Meals and FoodPlanerList is defined, but as no further info is given this cannot be resolved. If meals is a list, SelectMany would be the right function

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a list of lists. YOu say for each entry add this element to the output

```
p => p.Meals.ToList().Select(t => t.name).ToList<String>()
```

Which is a list. So its doing exactly waht you say. If you want a list of things then the `p=> thing` must return one element of the output

What are you trying to do and what does the FoodPlannerList look like (what type is it)

Comment: First of all, sorry for my bad english.  I have the class Foodplaner, and i return a List<Foodplaner>. Foodplaner has the fields                              public String FoodPlanName {get; set; }
public List<Meals> Meals {get; set;}          the Class Meals has a couple of fields, one of this fields is name. I try to show all Meal.name(s).

Comment: you need to use SelectMany if you want to flatten a list of lists into a list